# Finitely representable space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

**Background**:

Let $E,F$ be Banach spaces with $F$ be finitely representable in $E$, and separable.  That is, for all finite dimensional subspaces $M\subset F$ there is a $(1 + \epsilon)$-isomorphism (not necessarily surjective) $T:F\to E$.

Note: A $(1+\epsilon)$-isomorphism $T:M\to F$ is a linear operator such that $\|T\|,\|T^{-1}\|< (1+\epsilon)$, where $T^{-1}$ is restricted to the image of $T$.

---

**Question**:

How can I construct a linearly independent sequence $x_{n}\in F$ such that $\overline{\text{span}}\{x_{n}\} = F$?

---

**Context**:

I need to do so to follow the proof that under these hypotheses, $F$ isometrically embeds into $(E)_{\mathcal{U}}$ for all countably incomplete $\mathcal{U}$.

Comment: You can't do that in general because $\overline{\operatorname{span}\{x_n\}}=F\implies F\mbox{ is separable }$.

Comment: Thanks, suppose further that $F$ is separable.  I cleaned up my question which was sloppy, sorry!

Comment: I had an idea, but haven't checked it yet.  Just start with a countable dense subset and throw away the ones you dont need for linear independance.

Comment: OK.  I see the argument.  I almost want to delete the question now.  Thanks for any attention that has been given to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finite representability isn't even needed, but it is implicitly assumed that $F$ is infinite-dimensional.

Start with a countable dense subset $G\subset F$, which exists by separability.

Then choose a linearly independant sequence from elements of $G$, which must exist otherwise $F$ is finite-dimensional.